# Linear programming, theory of alternatives

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I need help proving this:
$Ax<b$  is feasible iff $y=0$ is the only solution of $y\geq0, yA=0, yb\leq0$.
It is referred to Carver's theorem (1921) is some books.